# Need to restrict a textbox input for a single decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm new to Jquery. I'm just trying to add only one single decimal value in a textbox using Regex. As it allows ".". But, I need to restrict to only one ".". Can any one suggest me in doing that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code is :

```
$("#cashReceived").filter_input({regex:'[0-9-.]'});
```

Thank you.

Comment: create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to allow only max but optional decimal point:

```
$("#cashReceived").filter_input({regex:'[-+]?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?'});
```

Comment: Are you able to produce a JSFIDDLE with your problem? You can also try this `regex:'[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+'`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [this plugin](http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/jquery-plugin-filter-text-input), you can't. You'd better find another library/plugin.

Reason: The plugin checks character by character (unless the user copy&paste the text).

Related part from [the code](http://www.thimbleopensource.com/download/jquery/jquery.filter_input.js):

```
...
if (event.type=='keypress') {

  var key = event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : 0;

  ...

  var string = String.fromCharCode(key);
  ...

if (regex.test(string)) {
```